# A Component Error has occurred! [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'linkId')]

Tags: component

I have been seeing this error for the past few months every time I open salesforce. In order to fix it, I have to refresh the screen multiple times. An additional issue I am seeing is that the accessibility buttons are enlarged and are also fixed by refreshing a few times. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

> Message-  [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'linkId')]
> File Name- `https://manh-login.lightning.force.com/components/lightning/tabBar.js`
> Line- 1
> Column- 10029

Comment: It seems like you have a component that is trying to load on the page but it's not loading. Do you have a custom app that maybe has some custom lightning component on it?